# Quickfix mode with path transformation

Tags: quickfix

I have a build log file from compiling a project with Visual Studio on a Windows machine, and would like to use quickfix mode to jump to the errors and warnings in that logfile.

The logfile is read correctly, and I get

```
(240 of 365649): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still uns...
```

in the bottommost line, but obviously the file cannot be opened because the path is from another machine.

Is there a way to transform the path names, and ignore warnings for files that cannot be found after transformation?

Comment: To clarify: log is from windows and has windows path separators? Machine you run `vim -q` is non-windows?

Comment: Your sample log line doesn't have any file paths in it... Did you mean to include some lines above or below that one for the full context? Also, what's your local machine like, is it a Linux/Unix host?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, exactly, so I need both support for Windows path separators and for mapping a path on the Windows machine to a local path. The latter alone would be useful already, as I also have build logs from another Linux machine.